# Different coloured section header backgrounds

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

I have three sections in my tableView. I am trying to set different background colours to each of the section headers. This is the example I have found to set the section colours, but I have not found a way to set different colours yet, is this possible?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Another way to set the background color
    // Note: does not preserve gradient effect of original header
    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: Change the color of header. `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Comment: But how do I set different colours, for example setting the first section to green, the second to yellow, the third to red?

Comment: Put the `section` in condition. If (section == 0) then green else if (section == 1) then yellow and so on.

Comment: you can use `if else` statement or `switch` statement to achieve this. As you can see the parameter `section` here is type of  `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSArray *backgroundColors;
    static NSArray *titleColors;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        backgroundColors = @[[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor]];
        titleColors = @[[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor]];
    });

    // Background color
    view.tintColor = backgroundColors[section];

    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:titleColors[section]];

    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[section];
}
```

Comment: Actually this did not work for me. I got a crash on the line [header.textLabel setTextColor:titleColors[section]];, and when I removed everything about titleColors, the background color was not changed.

Comment: It's just a example and you should use three colors for backgroundColors and titleColors, like this:`backgroundColors = @[[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor],[UIColor yellowColor]];`

Comment: This approach allows you to do very flexible expansion

Answer (score 0):

you can set different background color in this way.

**Adjust According to your Header Title and Color**

**Here is my Example:-**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
UITableViewHeaderFooterView * headerview = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
if (section==0)
{
headerview.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.90 green:0.60 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];
headerview.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
if (section==1) {
    headerview.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.50 green:0.0 blue:0.20 alpha:1.0];
    headerview.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

}
```

**Edit :**

To set  section empty you need to make array of section.
Example:-

```
    secnm=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"Friends", nil];
// Declaration of section array(set section according to your need)
```

> you need to set `""` to make empty section means without header.
>   and then set colour from your section `1` or sec `2` according to your requirement

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
UITableViewHeaderFooterView * headerview = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
 if (section==1) (set index according to your section)
{
    headerview.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.90 green:0.60 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];
    headerview.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 }

 }
```

Result :-

[image: Section without header and with header]

Comment: What if the first section is empty? Then the second section will get the first color, etc. How do I check how many sections there are?

Comment: please tickmark on right button so, it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of colours for your 3 sections like

```
NSArray *headerColors=@[[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor redColor]];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [headerColors objectAtIndex:section];

    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Another way to set the background color
    // Note: does not preserve gradient effect of original header
    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```